# Meaning of a vertical bar

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I've encountered something I haven't seen before. Could someone tell me what the following means:

x | 5

Comment: x divides 5.  No remainder left

Comment: means you can divide 5 by x without rest

Comment: @math12. No. It is exactly the opposite. You can divide 5 by x without a remainder.

Comment: corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$a|b$ means that you can divide b by a without getting a nonzero remainder.

Alternatively: $b$ is a multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

It means $5\div x$ is a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

The $ x | 5 $ expression would mean that any number $ x $ would be a divisor of $ 5 $ with no remainder. In other words, $ 5 $ would be evenly divisible by $ x $.